# Unsupported URL Swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, deserialization, nsurlsession

I am deserializing JSON is Swift 5. I am getting a strange error message I've never seen before.

```
2019-11-15 00:53:59.246948-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505805] Task <8291D72C-ACB0-4C9D-8169-60C8D38E6555>.<3> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-11-15 00:53:59.267601-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505806] Error fetching data Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000002557b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/03/MA15_Chili_Vegetarian_0104_rt_800x800.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/03/MA15_Chili_Vegetarian_0104_rt_800x800.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
2019-11-15 00:53:59.275585-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505805] Task <10DCC226-2F4F-4BF4-884E-B9878959D6A5>.<4> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-11-15 00:53:59.276525-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505806] Error fetching data Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000255690 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2014/06/FetaStuffedCherryTomatoes_267_600.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2014/06/FetaStuffedCherryTomatoes_267_600.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
2019-11-15 00:53:59.458865-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505803] Task <F36DF3CF-529F-461B-AF84-D6C07C1A1A36>.<5> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-11-15 00:53:59.459230-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505806] Error fetching data Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000255120 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2011/12/HCO_LemonDillGreekChickenSalad_178_600.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2011/12/HCO_LemonDillGreekChickenSalad_178_600.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
2019-11-15 00:53:59.477245-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505804] Task <B3F9DD43-4AD6-4D4F-BD49-679C5CA59D05>.<6> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-11-15 00:53:59.478623-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505806] Error fetching data Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000255e70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/TurkeyTacoCups_259_600x600.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/TurkeyTacoCups_259_600x600.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
2019-11-15 00:53:59.727535-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505803] Task <99D0917B-BED2-4728-A6A0-BC94B50809A0>.<7> finished with error - code: -1002
2019-11-15 00:53:59.728287-0800 WW-Exercise-01[14071:7505806] Error fetching data Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000254280 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/LemonyBeetHummus_052_800x800.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/LemonyBeetHummus_052_800x800.jpg, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

Here's my JSON

```
[
  {
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/07/TANDORI_GRILLED_SHRIMP_1053_800x800.jpg",
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_cooking method.tags:Grilling\\\"]",
    "title": "Summer Grilling"
  },
  {
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2013/09/MediterraneanBeanSalad_1187_600.jpg",
    "title": "Latest",
    "filter": ""
  },
  {
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_other.tags:Quick & Easy\\\"]",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2014/07/BeanCheeseHotDogs_052_600.jpg",
    "title": "Quick & Easy"
  },
  {
    "title": "No-Cook",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/LemonyBeetHummus_052_800x800.jpg",
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_cooking method.tags:No-Cook\\\"]"
  },
  {
    "title": "Family-Friendly",
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_other.tags:Family-Friendly\\\"]",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/08/TurkeyTacoCups_259_600x600.jpg"
  },
  {
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_season.tags:Summer\\\"], [\\\"contentTags.food_season.tags:Spring\\\"]",
    "title": "Seasonal",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2011/12/HCO_LemonDillGreekChickenSalad_178_600.jpg"
  },
  {
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_cuisines.tags:American\\\"]",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/03/MA15_Chili_Vegetarian_0104_rt_800x800.jpg",
    "title": "American"
  },
  {
    "title": "Italian",
    "image": "/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2014/06/FetaStuffedCherryTomatoes_267_600.jpg",
    "filter": "[\\\"contentTags.food_cuisines.tags:Italian\\\"]"
  }
]
```

What am I missing? My JSON I valid. I get back the `title` and `filter` but not the image.

Here's my model

```
struct Person: Codable {
  let image: String
  let filter: String
  let title: String
}
```

Here's my Extension

```
// MARK: - Local cache for saving images in memory

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCache(with urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        // check for cached image

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        // otherwise download image

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("Error fetching data \(error)")
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The message `unsupported URL` is quite meaningful, isn't it? For example where is scheme and host?

Comment: @vadian `static let url = URL(string: "https://www.weightwatchers.com/assets/cmx/us/messages/collections.json")!`

Comment: @vadian I'm using a simple `URLSession` and setting the downloaded data to my empty array. What is wrong with the URL?

Comment: your URL is incorrect. Can you share your full code where you transform your "image" string object into an URL?

Comment: I'm just reading the error message. It clearly states that the scheme (`https://`) and host (presumably) `weightwatchers.com` is missing in `/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/03/MA15_Chili_Vegetarian_0104_rt_800x800.jpg`. It looks like you are trying to load the image at the URLs in the JSON after receiving the data.

Comment: @vadian let me try that. I added my extension.

Comment: @Zun added the extension

Comment: Please read Joakim's answer carefully. You have to insert `https://weightwatchers.com` at the beginning of the URL string before calling `URL(string`. Replace `guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }` with `guard let url = URL(string: "https://weightwatchers.com" + urlString) else { return }`

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: No you are not doing that **in the extension**. See the error message. It's printed multiple times (once for each image URL)

Comment: you have to add the scheme and the domain in front of your image url. it's 100% correct and your fault that `/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/03/MA15_Chili_Vegetarian_0104_rt_800x800.jpg` isn't a valid URL.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. That was not intuitive to me and should have been.

Answer (score 5):

You can't have an URL without a protocol type like http, ftp etc

So if your images are stored locally it should be something like

"file://images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/07/TANDORI_GRILLED_SHRIMP_1053_800x800.jpg"

but if they are on a server then you are not just missing the http(s) part but the whole server address

"http://127.0.0.1/images/1033/dynamic/foodandrecipes/2015/07/TANDORI_GRILLED_SHRIMP_1053_800x800.jpg"

*Update*

For your extension I would suggest using the `URLComponents` class to build a correct url

```
var urlComponent = URLComponents()

urlComponent.scheme = "https"
urlComponent.host = "www.weightwatchers.com"
urlComponent.path = urlString

guard let url = urlComponent.url else { return }
```

Comment: My URL looks like this `static let url = URL(string: "https://www.weightwatchers.com/assets/cmx/us/messages/collections.json")!`

Comment: Are you saying I need to add a local address prefix even if the images exist on a server?

Comment: @David Look at the error message, that is not the URL the error message is about. Look for NSErrorFailingURLStringKey in the message. My local address was only an example, you need to use a complete URL.

Comment: I see `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey` but I don't understand the error. My JSON key "image" is failing?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are turning the image key into an URL object.

Comment: Yes, I have an extension for caching images. Let me look!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
```

with

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://[[ENTER_THE_FULL_LINK_HERE_PLEASE]]\(urlString)") else { return }
```